# Dynamically Set Taskbar Icon for Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows

My company has a branding mechanism that sets the icon for a Windows Application, like so:

```
if (AppBranding.Is("FOO"))
    Icon = MyProject.Properties.Resources.Icon_FOO;
else
    Icon = MyProject.Properties.Resources.Icon_BAR;
```

`Icon_FOO` and `Icon_BAR` are resources that point to their respective .ico files.

Also, Icon and manifest in Project > MyProject Properties > Resources is set in Visual Studio.

[image]

When users launch the application, the correct icon appears based on branding. However, if they pin the program to the taskbar, the icon reverts to Icon_FOO.ico, regardless of branding. When they unpin it, the icon toggles back.

I believe that programs pinned to the taskbar use the icon of the .exe, while the icon for the Window is whatever I set `Form.Icon` to be. I only know how to set the .exe icon by going to Project Properties > Resources and making a selection from the drop down list, as I have in the picture above. How can the icon for the .exe be set dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

The icon in the taskbar is (usually) the first icon resource available in the assembly, and cannot be modified from within the application (unless you create a custom shortcut programmatically).

Instead of trying to manipulate this, you can create a simple starter application (*.exe) with the correct icon and version attributes for each branded version? The .exe than only needs to load the application from an assembly that contains the actual application content.

so you have

```
Launcher_FOO.exe
Launcher_BAR.exe
```

with their own custom icons. Both application will create a common application from

```
Actual_Application.dll
```

to start the application.

You may use `Reflection.Emit` to create the Launcher_xxx.exe on the fly:

see [google search](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=reflection.emit%20create%20assembly%20with%20resources)

see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt9483fk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I may have oversimplified my example in the question while trying to make it easier for StackOverflow to read. Our customers get an unbranded application. They provide a license file that contains the brand, and suddenly all of the relevant banners and icons change. Your solution requires that the brand be known at compile-time, when we can only know it at run-time. To top it all off, our solution was working fine until someone decided to pin the program to the taskbar. I need a *dynamic* way to change the taskbar icon.

Comment: @John, ok, i understand your requirement, but i don't think that there's a dynamic solution for this, without altering the shortcut, or the binary itself (which would not be a great solution, given virus scanners etc.. that check for this kind of thing). If your application is signed, than you cannot modify the application without resigning.